# Iotivity : Build the C++ examples

Tags: c++, iot, iotivity

I have just started with iotivity and have been reading the documentation. On [this setup page](https://www.iotivity.org/documentation/linux/getting-started), under the heading **running the c++ samples**, it tells how to run the examples, but before that I should build them first and it seems the page `Build the C++ samples` it refers to, is missing.

When I tried to build the examples in a normal way using `g++`, it gave some missing header errors, meaning that's not the right way or will take a lot of effort.

Do any one know how to build the examples packet with iotivity release?

Comment: @Amadeus : Oops sorry... Its fine now

Comment: On the link that you provided, there is no heading **running the c++ samples**

Comment: @Amadeus : Search for **running the samples**

Answer (score 0):

Place the following makefile in the *iotivity/resource/examples* directory :

```
IDIR=-I../include -I./../csdk/stack/include/ -I./../c_common/ -I./../oc_logger/include
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 $(IDIR) -loc -loctbstack -loc_logger -lpthread
SERV_OBJ = simpleserver.o
CLIENT_OBJ = simpleclient.o

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

#Build the simpleserver executable
all:simpleserver simpleclient
simpleserver:$(SERV_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

#Build the simpleclient executable
simpleclient:$(CLIENT_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

and then hit `make` on the terminal. Then execute `simpleclient` and `simpleserver` on two different terminals. In case you get the error :

```
./simpleclient: error while loading shared libraries: liboc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

type the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../../out/linux/x86_64/release
```

Answer (score 0):

I researched a lot to find where the executables get generated for the c++ samples, finally found the path.

On 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,
when iotivity is built as follows:

> $ scons

the executables get created in path `/iotivity/out/linux/x86_64/release/resource/examples` for the code present in `/iotivity/resource/examples` so you can just go to `/iotivity/out/linux/x86_64/release/resource/examples` and execute simpleserver(**./simpleserver**) and simpleclient(**./simpleclient**)

Answer (score -2):

Check this page about IoTivity supported (and unsupported) examples :

https://wiki.iotivity.org/examples#

```
cd ${project_dir}/out/${TARGET_OS}/${TARGET_ARCH}/${BUILD_MODE}/resource/examples/
killall simpleserver simpleclient # make sure none are running

./simpleserver 2>&1 | tee simpleserver.log.txt &
./simpleclient 2>&1 | tee simpleclient.log.txt
```

Some c++ examples are not working in 1.3.0 while 1.2.1 should be ok

But if you want to build other examples from outside the main tree, I made a dedicated project that use gnu make.

Hope this helps